# XmlPullParser Android - additional tags

Tags: android, xmlpullparser, android-xmlpullparser

This my source for parsing, which I insert to database below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
   <Document>
      <Count>2</Count>
      <Filters>
         <MEMBER_UNI>1775W585_2/00323</MEMBER_UNI>
      </Filters>
      <Placemark id="placemarkfe0f3016-37e1-4c7d-b453-2d9a3fbd4947">
         <name>streetLighting.lightingPoint</name>
         <guid>fe0f3016-37e1-4c7d-b453-2d9a3fbd4947</guid>
         <description>geom</description>
         <Point>
            <coordinates>-1.0542558191173,50.834675625281</coordinates>
         </Point>
         <GlobalID>dbfedcfd-c0d6-494c-8d9d-0204dbdb8157</GlobalID>
         <IIT_ID_C_1>1</IIT_ID_C_1>
         <IIT_X_SE_1>1</IIT_X_SE_1>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark id="placemark5b53ebbf-3672-4b29-a702-f44a96fed4be">
         <name>streetLighting.lightingPoint</name>
         <guid>5b53ebbf-3672-4b29-a702-f44a96fed4be</guid>
         <description>geom</description>
         <Point>
            <coordinates>-1.0542861954769,50.834426772517</coordinates>
         </Point>
         <GlobalID>3e485808-7b64-4e5f-95a8-94cd90aea900</GlobalID>
         <IIT_ID_C_1>Feb-29</IIT_ID_C_1>
         <IIT_X_SE_1>2</IIT_X_SE_1>
      </Placemark>
   </Document>
</kml>
```

And below there is my code, which should be changed, Any ideas? I need avoid

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

XmlResourceParser parser = context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.test1);
        databaseHelper myDbHelper = new databaseHelper(context);
        try {
            while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    continue;
                }
                String name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equals("Placemark") || name.equals("Count")) { 
                    String id = null, gname = null, pob = null, pob1 = null, memb = null, seq = null, site = null;
                    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        name = parser.getName();
                        if (name.equals("name")) {
                            id = readText(parser);
                        } else if (name.equals("description")) {
                            parser.next();
                            parser.nextTag();
                        } else if (name.equals("guid")) {
                            gname = readText(parser);
                        } else if (name.equals("Point")) {
                            parser.nextTag();
                            if (parser.getName().equals("coordinates")) {

                                pob = readText(parser);
                                String[] pobarray = pob.split(",");
                                String part1 = pobarray[0];
                                String part2 = pobarray[1];

                                pob1 = part2;
                                pob = part1;
                                parser.nextTag();
                            }
                        } else if (name.equals("MEMBER_UNI")) {
                            memb = readText(parser);
                        } else if (name.equals("IIT_ID_C_1")) {
                            seq = readText(parser);
                        } else if (name.equals("IIT_X_SE_1")) {
                            site = readText(parser);
                        }
                    }
                    myDbHelper.insertData(id, gname, pob, pob1, memb, seq, site);
                }
            }
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (myDbHelper != null) {
                myDbHelper.close();
            }
        }
    return null;
}
```

In my view it should be changed for something simpler, and clever.

Comment: Please format your question so it can be read without having to scroll all the time.

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: How to insert to database values from member_uni

Comment: I need new parser, because this is out of date